# JQuery's get in combination with Angular not linking scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, scope

I'm currently working on a project that involves both JQuery and Angular.
I need to be able to show HTML on a page depending on the user input, because of the large amount I thought of getting the html from an external file, compile it and add it to the main html. It works however it still showes the litteral text between brackets instead of the value. {{ controller.someValue }} instead of f.e. 6.

Can somebody perhaps help me?:

*Edit*, added some more relevant code

```
angular.module('Metrovoly').controller("SettingsController", function($scope, $filter, $stateParams, personFactory, $compile) {

var controller = this;

this.setSelectedGear = function(index, divNameOne, divNameTwo ,event, typeOfGear){

  $(".editContainer").children().remove();

  $.get("/templates/pages/gear/" + typeOfGear + ".html", function(data){
        var el = $compile(data)($scope);
        $(".editContainer").append(el);
    });

};
```

HTML from link:

```
  <p>Name:</p>
  <p> {{ settingsController.personData.selectedPerson.name }}</p>
```

Comment: Could you show more of the code you are speaking about inside your description?

Comment: You do not need to write `{{ controller.someValue }}` try with `{{ someValue }}`.

Comment: That didn't work, I added some more relevant code :)

Comment: Maybe the problem is you try to add angular-compiled data with a jquery function. Try using:

 `var container = document.querySelector('.editContainer');

angular.element(container).append(el);`

Comment: Where do you add personData to the scope? Are you sure it is there? Also change the html to: 

`{{ personData.selectedPerson.name }}`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Both did not seem to help, I'm sure the data is there. The same happens with a simple "testValue".

Comment: Okay, instead of `var el = $compile(data)($scope);` try `container.innerHTML = $sce.trustAsHtml(data));`. Maybe the problem is that you have 2 elements inside your file, while you try to compile them as one element.

Comment: I then receive an eroor that $sce is not defined

Comment: Of course, you need to inject it to the controller: `angular.module('Metrovoly').controller("SettingsController", function($scope, $filter, $stateParams, personFactory, $sce)`.

Comment: That did not help also, I appreciate the help, however I think I'm thinking to difficult, so I'm going to use it a different way. Again thanks for your help :)

Comment: No problem. It is bad to mix jQuery and Angular, but if you have to use jQuery, then at least try to use Angular logic on all possible places. It is a good prectice and it will pay off in the long run. (:

Comment: Angular has an '$http' service for performing asynchronous calls. There's no reason to use any of the jquery methods for http requests.